# How to get date string from day number and month number using moment?

Tags: javascript, momentjs

dayNumber: 28,
monthNumber: 2,

**expected output using moment "2022-02-28"**

What I've tried   `const date = moment() .month(monthNumber) .days(dayNumber) .format("YYYY-MM-DD");`

but that gives me something like "2022-03-17"

what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two errors in your code:

- The first one is that you need to replace the `days` function call with `date`
- The second one is that the argument of the `month` function starts from 0. So 0 is January, 1 is February etc.

So, what you need to do in order to get **2022-02-28** is the following:

```js
const date = moment() .month(1) .date(28) .format("YYYY-MM-DD");
```

Answer (score 2):

`.month` expects values from 0-11. See: https://momentjs.com/docs/#/get-set/month/

`.days` is day of week, `.date` is day of month. See: https://momentjs.com/docs/#/get-set/day/ and https://momentjs.com/docs/#/get-set/date/

```js
 const date = moment().month(monthNumber-1).date(dayNumber).format("YYYY-MM-DD");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also create a moment instance with an array of numbers that mirror the parameters passed to new Date(), e.g. [year, month, day].

See [`moment/parsing/array`](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/array/)

NB: Month is zero-indexed.

```js
const year = 2022;
const monthNumber = 2;
const dayNumber = 28;

console.log(moment([year, monthNumber - 1, dayNumber]).format('YYYY-MM-DD'))
```

```html
<script src="https://momentjs.com/downloads/moment.js"></script>
```